# Facebook Like - Shows 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-401, sharethis

I am adding [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/) widget. When i try to like the page it gives me an Error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say with that little information, but i am pretty sure the URL you want to share includes authorization. Shared/Liked URLs should always be public, or Facebook can't access the Open Graph data (obviously).

Edit: I just debugged the domain and while there is no authorization, you do get that error. So i would assume it´s a bug. Here is where you can debug URLs and refresh their OG tags: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

I did refresh the tags and the error did not disappear, so you should consider filing a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: any idea how to debug it? which direction i should look into

Comment: if the url you want to share/like is hidden behind authorization, what do you want to debug? at least add the url you want to share/like to your question.

Comment: ...or is it just creosense.com? you need to be more specific.

Comment: oh i changed the plugin :)

Comment: what does that mean? did you have an authorization before?